# Poor Excel add-in performance unless debugger is attached

Tags: excel, performance, office-js

I am developing an Excel Taskpane add-in that writes and reads data from Ranges upon a WebSockets message (using socket.io). These operations take 4-5 seconds to perform, unless I attach a debugger (be it DevTools or Visual Studio's), which noticeably improves performance (to around 100ms). The debugger doesn't even have to stay attached, the performance improvement stays until the add-in is restarted.

Some details:

- The ranges are no usually no bigger than 10 cells.
- I've tried using both, debug and non-debug versions of Office.js
- The issue happens on both read and write operations
- I'm 99% percent certain that the delay occurs within Excel.run functions (and has nothing to do with socket.io or another library)
- My Excel version is 1902 (build 11328.20146).
- I'm using TypeScript and Webpack to bundle the addin.
- I've tried bluebird and es6-promise's Promise polyfill

The only reference I've found so far about this issue is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51100684/office-js-excel-performance-issue-without-microsoft-edge-devtools), that never got answered. He seems to have experienced the exact same issue as I.

A reading operation example:

```
public async ReadObjectAsync(row) 
{
    var thisReader = this;

    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => 
    {
        try
        {
            await Excel.run(async (context) =>
            {
                var object = {}
                var boundingRectangle : Excel.Range = null;

                var mappedControllers = QuoteAttributeArray.map(function(attribute) // Creamos un objeto con pares de atributo y controlador
                {
                    return arrayFind(thisReader.AppContext.AttributeControllers, function(controller)
                    {
                        return controller.TargetAttribute == attribute;
                    })
                });

                for(var i = 0; i < QuoteAttributeArray.length; i++)
                {
                    var attribute = QuoteAttributeArray[i];
                    var controller = (mappedControllers[i] as ExcelAttributeController);

                    if(controller.ColumnSelector.SelectedColumnLetter == null)
                    {
                        object[attribute] = null;
                        continue;
                    }

                    var ws = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();

                    var targetRange = ws.getRange(controller.ColumnSelector.SelectedColumnLetter + row);

                    if(boundingRectangle == null)
                    {
                        boundingRectangle = targetRange;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        boundingRectangle = boundingRectangle.getBoundingRect(targetRange); // Construimos el bounding rectangle atributo por atributo
                    }

                    if(controller.AttributeInput instanceof PlazoAttributeInput)
                    {
                        targetRange.load('text');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        targetRange.load('values');
                    }

                    boundingRectangle.load('address');

                    await context.sync();

                    if(controller.AttributeInput instanceof PlazoAttributeInput)
                    {
                        object[attribute] = targetRange.text[0];    
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        object[attribute] = targetRange.values[0];
                    }

                }

                var result = {
                    'boundingRectangleAddress' : boundingRectangle.address,
                    'object' : object
                };

                resolve(result);
            });
        }
        catch(error)
        {
            reject(error);
        }
    })
}
```

For some context: this function returns an object that represents a book, as in

```
{
 isbn: '9788798',
 title : 'Blahblah'
 author : 'Blahblah'
}
```

that is read from a single row in Excel. Items in 'QuoteAttributeArray' are the different attributes of a book (15 max) that were previously 'mapped' to columns.

This same function takes 4 seconds to execute when requested from a socket message, 1 second when the request is made within the addin, and 100ms (from socket and within the addin) after attaching the debugger.

**Solutions tried**

I refactored the function to make only one context.sync() call. It does improve significantly (to around ~300ms on the first execution and ~30ms afterwards, without the debugger) but there's still a difference when I attach the debugger (~20ms or less from the first time onwards). I guess this means the multiple context.sync() calls only amplify the delay, but it's still there. Here's my refactored version:

```
   public async ReadObjectAsync(row) 
{
    var thisReader = this;

    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => 
    {
        try
        {
            return await Excel.run(async (context) =>
            {


                var object = {}
                var boundingRectangle : Excel.Range = null;

                var mappedControllers = QuoteAttributeArray.map(function(attribute) // Creamos un objeto con pares de atributo y controlador
                {
                    return arrayFind(thisReader.AppContext.AttributeControllers, function(controller)
                    {
                        return controller.TargetAttribute == attribute;
                    })
                });

                let attributeRanges = {};

                for(let i = 0; i< QuoteAttributeArray.length; i++)
                {
                    var attribute = QuoteAttributeArray[i];
                    var controller = (mappedControllers[i] as ExcelAttributeController);

                    if(controller.ColumnSelector.SelectedColumnLetter == null)
                    {
                        object[attribute] = null;
                        continue;
                    }

                    var ws = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();

                    var targetRange = ws.getRange(controller.ColumnSelector.SelectedColumnLetter + row);

                    if(boundingRectangle == null)
                    {
                        boundingRectangle = targetRange;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        boundingRectangle = boundingRectangle.getBoundingRect(targetRange); // Construimos el bounding rectangle atributo por atributo
                    }

                    if(controller.AttributeInput instanceof PlazoAttributeInput)
                    {
                        console.log('attribute :' + attribute)
                        targetRange.load('text');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        console.log('nonPlazo :' + attribute)
                        targetRange.load('values');
                    }

                    attributeRanges[attribute] = targetRange;
                }

                boundingRectangle.load('address');

                return context.sync().then(() =>
                {
                    for(var attribute in attributeRanges)
                    {
                        if(attribute == 'plazo')
                        {
                            object[attribute] = attributeRanges[attribute].text[0];    
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            object[attribute] = attributeRanges[attribute].values[0];
                        }

                    }

                    var result = {
                        'boundingRectangleAddress' : boundingRectangle.address,
                        'object' : object
                    };

                    return resolve(result);
                });
            });
        }
        catch(error)
        {
            return reject(error);
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Can you please share part of the code which you are experiencing performance problems, along with the build number?

Comment: @MaviDomates Excel build number, right? Done. Thanks Mavi

Comment: Can you please add a return statement infront of your resolve and rejects?

Comment: Done. No luck, still takes ~4 seconds to read.

Comment: Add a return in front of the  `await Excel.run`

Comment: context.sync also requires a callback right? But it's not a promise based thing, so I'm not sure if you can await that.

Comment: Done, still the same. I've been trying to pinpoint the delay, and I found that the culprit is each context.sync() inside the QuoteItemAttributeArray loop. Without attaching the debugger, the first ones take around 300ms, with the last ones taking around 20ms each (some 300ms ones in the middle, too, sometimes). When I attach the debugger, each one takes no more than 20ms.

Comment: Try using the callback for the context.sync((result) => {})

Comment: It might be that it doesn't support async / await

Comment: I'll try that. Just a second

Comment: I've refactored the function a little. It did improve significantly (w/o debugger: around 300ms for the first request, ~30ms after, w/debugger: around ~20ms from the first time onwards), as it doesn't call context.sync() for each item in QuoteAttributeArray. It kinda works, but there's still a significant difference with and without attaching the debugger (which was only amplified because of the multiple context.sync() calls). I'll add my refactoring to the main post

Comment: I've also checked the documentation for context.sync() and it does return a Promise object